# Issues using clang in cpp

Tags: c++, clang

Im trying to learn cpp and im working with a macbook air M1. Im using VSCode for IDE and i have some issues with clang.

It doesnt want declarations like this
`int number{100};` but its working with `int number = 100;` (i saw the first line in an online course)

cant use separators like :  `long long big_number = 14'500'350;`

this code :

```
#include <iostream> 
int main(){
    int number=100;
    std::cout << number << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

is showing me this in the debuging console :

```
=thread-selected,id="1"
=library-unloaded,id="/Users/superneiluj/Desktop/cpp/hello world/variables",target-name="/Users/superneiluj/Desktop/cpp/hello world/variables",host-name="/Users/superneiluj/Desktop/cpp/hello world/variables"
Loaded '/usr/lib/dyld'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/Users/superneiluj/Desktop/cpp/hello world/variables'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_collections.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_featureflags.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_product_info_filter.dylib'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/liboah.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
100
The program '/Users/superneiluj/Desktop/cpp/hello world/variables' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).
```

But its not working in my terminal when i try this

```
g++ -std=c++17 variables.cpp -o variables
./variables
```

its showing nothing

The thing i dont understand is that its working well with a simple Hello world like this
:

```
#include <iostream> 
int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

with command lines :

```
g++ -std=c++17 helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
./helloworld
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the compiler that's giving you errors or just your IDE (fancy editor which is irrelevant to correctness).?

Comment: The code in the first block won't compile. `big_number` is undefined.

Comment: Apple clang defaults to C++98 *for reasons*. You need to actually configure VS Code to explicitly use whatever standard you want. Looks like a minimum of C++14. You also might be looking in the wrong tab. Hard to say. It's not an issue on Apple's end.

Comment: @RetiredNinja sorry it was a bad copy/paste, i fixed the original post

Comment: @JesperJuhl i dont have any errors with me IDE or terminal

Comment: @sweenish i dont have issues with VS Code, i dont understand why its working with VS Code but not with command line in a terminal

Comment: "Loaded '/usr/lib/system..." - those are not compiler errors. Those are errors from your editor/IDE. Your compiler is fine - you invoked it from the command line with no errors. You need to learn what tools are involved in compiling a C++ program.

Comment: There are still inconsistencies in the question. Like the final block compiling an executable called `helloworld` but then running `variables`. The provided information is nearly all inconsequential to the problem being experienced. And why you're complaining about clang but invoking gcc.

Comment: There are two very different problems. The problem with VS Code is that you are not using the C++ standard from this here millennium. Figure out how to configure your `tasks.json` or whatever to pass `-std=c++17` to the compiler. The other problem is compiling a specific program by running the compiler from the terminal. The two problems are unrelated. Please ask two separate questions.

Comment: At this point, I just think you forgot to save the file.

Comment: @n.m. i understand that, ill give it a try

Comment: @sweenish no, another bad copy/paste, my bad